# Could not find Doxygen (missing: DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, doxygen

I want to install meta on my Mac OS X. I have OS X 10.9.3, and I received the following errors:

```
   DICU_ROOT=/usr/local/opt/icu4c
-- Compiler supports C++1y (using it)
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
-- Locating libc++...
-- Located libc++, using it.
--     Locating libc++'s abi...
--     Found libc++abi, using it.
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/sara/meta/build
MacBook-Air:build sara$ brew install DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE
Error: No available formula for doxygen_executable 
Searching formulae...
Searching taps...
saras-MacBook-Air:build sara$ meta
-bash: meta: command not found
saras-MacBook-Air:build sara$ build
-bash: build: command not found
```

Comment: Doxygen isn't install by default; use [macports](http://macports.org) to install it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Doxygen isn't installed by default. You can download it using `brew`.

```
$ brew info doxygen
doxygen: stable 1.8.9.1 (bottled), HEAD
http://www.doxygen.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/doxygen/1.8.9.1 (5 files, 15M) *
  Poured from bottle
From:      https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/doxygen.rb
==> Dependencies
Optional: graphviz ✘
==> Options
--with-doxywizard
    Build GUI frontend with qt support.
--with-graphviz
    Build with dot command support from Graphviz.
--with-libclang
    Build with libclang support.
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version

$brew install doxygen
```

Answer (score 0):

`brew install --head doxygen` worked for me

```
mahesh@Maheshs-MacBook-Air-M1 glfw-3.3.7 % brew install --head doxygen
Warning: Treating doxygen as a formula. For the cask, use homebrew/cask/doxygen
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/bison/manifests/3.8.2
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/bison/blobs/sha256:78ce4e93936c
==> Downloading from https://pkg-containers.githubusercontent.com/ghcr1/blobs/sh
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Cloning https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen.git
Cloning into '/Users/mahesh/Library/Caches/Homebrew/doxygen--git'...
==> Checking out branch master
Already on 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
Warning: Your Xcode (13.2.1) is outdated.
Please update to Xcode 13.3 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.

==> Installing dependencies for doxygen: bison
==> Installing doxygen dependency: bison
==> Pouring bison--3.8.2.arm64_monterey.bottle.tar.gz
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/bison/3.8.2: 99 files, 3.7MB
==> Installing doxygen --HEAD
==> cmake ..
==> make
==> make install
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/doxygen/HEAD-5ef4fee: 5 files, 18.9MB, built in 1 minute 1 second
==> Running `brew cleanup doxygen`...
Disable this behaviour by setting HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP.
Hide these hints with HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_HINTS (see `man brew`).
```

source https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/41441